# sending image in mail in asp

Tags: c#, image

i am using c# code to sent the mail to another user.
it works fine when i send text in it..
now i want to send image so that the image what i sent should open in his inbox. means the image should go as message body not the attachments..
i am using the code to sent the image as:

```
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach =
                new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(
                    "C:\\Documents and Settings\\All Users\\Documents\\My Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Winter.jpg");
            Random Rgen = new Random();
            attach.ContentId = Rgen.Next(100000, 9999999).ToString();
            attach.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
  MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
 m.From = new MailAddress("swe@gmail.com");
            m.To.Add(new MailAddress("qwe@gmail.com"));
  m.IsBodyHtml = true;

            m.Body = "<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src='cid:" + attach.ContentId + "'></body></html>";
            //m.Body = inline.ToString();
            // m.Body = "<img src='cid:" + attach.ContentId + "'>";
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("swe@gmail.com", "swe");
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            client.Send(m);
```

but it is not sending the image as message..

please help me out..

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you build your attachment

```
attach.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
attach.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
attach.ContentId = contentID;
attach.ContentType.MediaType = "image/png";
```

Remove the img tag from the body and just do `m.Attachments.Add(attach);`

Comment: @V4Vendetta: it sends the text which i give in m.body... as"<html><body><h1>Picture</h1><br><img src='cid:433046'></body></html>"

Comment: Then you should set `IsBodyHtml` to true for `MailMessage` instance

Answer (score 0):

i think all u have to do is to specify the format of ur mail. i.e.

```
m.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
```

maybe this will give u an alter idea. I had a similar task (coded it for intranet). so... what i did was - uploaded images to webserver, so that i already had URI's. and in code-behind i used these URIs as a src of the image.

```
mail.Body = "<html><body><img src='" + img_uri + "'></body></html>";
```

Comment: MailMessage.BodyFormat is deprecated and part of System.Web.Mail.MailMessage.

It would appear that the author is using System.Net.Mail...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: Found [here](http://aspalliance.com/1354_Sending_HTML_Mail_with_Embedded_Image_in_NET.all)

```
Public Sub EmbeddedImages()

        'create the mail message
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()

        'set the addresses
        mail.From = New MailAddress("from@fromdomain.com", " Display Name")
        mail.To.Add("to@todomain.com")

        'set the content
        mail.Subject = "This is an embedded image mail"

        'first we create the Plain Text part
        Dim palinBody As String = "This is my plain text content, viewable by
        those clients that don't support html"
        Dim plainView As AlternateView =
        AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(palinBody, Nothing,
        "text/plain")
        'then we create the Html part
        'to embed images, we need to use the prefix 'cid' in the img src value
        Dim htmlBody As String = "<b>This is the embedded image 
        file.</b><DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>"
        htmlBody += "<img alt="""" hspace=0 src=""cid:uniqueId"" align=baseline 
        border=0 >"
        htmlBody += "<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV><b>This is the end of Mail...</b>"
        Dim htmlView As AlternateView =
         AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, Nothing,
         "text/html")

        'create the AlternateView for embedded image
        Dim imageView As New AlternateView("c:\attachment\image1.jpg",
        MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg)
        imageView.ContentId = "uniqueId"
        imageView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64

        'add the views
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(plainView)
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView)
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(imageView)

        'send mail
        SendMail(mail)

End Sub ' End EmbedImages
```

HTH